Backfill civicrm_mailing unknown error when upgrading to 5.76.0
Environment:  Wordpress 6.6.1
Each month I checked the release notes for the latest release and install it in production.
This month I didn't see any special steps that should be taken when upgrading from 5.75.1 to 5.76.0 so I followed my usual deployment:

downloading the latest zip file from civicrm using wget
removing the civicrm plugin directory and unzipping the zip file
running the upgrade tool:  wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fupgrade&reset=1

When running the tool I get the following error:
[Error: Backfill civicrm_mailing start_date, end_date, status (7 => 42)]
Message DB Error: unknown error
Mode    16
UserInfo    UPDATE civicrm_mailing m INNER JOIN (SELECT MIN(job.start_date) as start_date, MAX(job.end_date) as end_date, job.mailing_id FROM civicrm_mailing_job job WHERE job.status = "Complete" GROUP BY job.mailing_id ) as job ON job.mailing_id = m.id SET m.status = "Complete", start_date = job.start_date, end_date = job.end_date, is_completed = 1 WHERE (m.status IS NULL OR m.status = "Draft") AND m.id BETWEEN 7 AND 42 [nativecode=1052 ** Column 'start_date' in field list is ambiguous]
DebugInfo   UPDATE civicrm_mailing m INNER JOIN (SELECT MIN(job.start_date) as start_date, MAX(job.end_date) as end_date, job.mailing_id FROM civicrm_mailing_job job WHERE job.status = "Complete" GROUP BY job.mailing_id ) as job ON job.mailing_id = m.id SET m.status = "Complete", start_date = job.start_date, end_date = job.end_date, is_completed = 1 WHERE (m.status IS NULL OR m.status = "Draft") AND m.id BETWEEN 7 AND 42 [nativecode=1052 ** Column 'start_date' in field list is ambiguous]
Civi\Core\Exception\DBQueryException: DB Error: unknown error in /bitnami/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src/PEAR.php on line 945

DB_Error: DB Error: unknown error in unknown on line unknown


It appears that there's a problem with the civicrm_mailing_job table.  I have upgraded just fine until this release.  Any ideas how to fix this so that I can upgrade?

UPDATE: 5.76.1 is now available for download with the below fix.

Can you change these two lines from
start_date = job.start_date,
end_date = job.end_date,

to
m.start_date = job.start_date,
m.end_date = job.end_date,

and see if that fixes it.

I had the same error and this fixed it.

Yes, making this change allowed the upgrade to proceed without error. Thanks for such a quick response! I have marked your comment as the answer

Thanks for the confirmations. Have put up PRs https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/30825 and https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/30826.

Worked for me as well.  Thank you!

It worked here as well. Thanks.
